# Sections and new pages

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I programmed the following command for my personal \section:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{
    \vspace*{.9cm} \textcolor{blue} {\large \bfseries #1} 
    \vspace*{-.3cm}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    }
```

then I did the same for a \subsection:

```
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{
   \vspace*{.6cm} \textcolor{blue}{\bfseries #1} \vspace*{.1cm}  \hspace*{.1cm} 
   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1} 
   }
```

Unfortunaltely, the text is now - unlike it is with a normal subsection - not put onto the same page as its subsection-title but is just randomly split...

What can I do against this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: you redefine `\section` on `\mysection` or you need the both

Comment: You should use latex's heading functions to define a heading, latex has _lots_ of code to prevent page breaks just after a heading or after just one line of the section and your definitions disable all that,